# looking for value in a panda dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with three columns,

```
    A       B     C
    One     2     1
    Two     3     0.5
    Three   6     7
```

I have a list which represents the second and third columns:
[(3,0.5),(6,7),(2,1)]

based on that list I want to retrieve the value in the first columns as a list:
[Two, Three, One]

How can I do that?
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set columns `B` and `C` as multi index and then query it with the list:

```
idx = [(3,0.5),(6,7),(2,1)]
df.set_index(['B', 'C']).A.loc[idx].values
# array(['Two', 'Three', 'One'], dtype=object)
```

If you need a list as result, use `tolist` as @Jezrael's comment.